# PyAudio send different frequency

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I want to send different frequency waves using PyAudio (I want to start with low and high for BFSK and maybe something more complex latter).

How I can do this? ( I know how to read which frequency is it using simple FFT, but no how to send).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you got any examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I didn't try, I read the doc and didn't found any clue so I asked here to find someone that maybe was in my position and figure it out